# how to run a jest test in a custom context?

Tags: variables, testing, jestjs, global

Goal: I have a set of global variables that I want to override in my tests without editing the global space.
For that, I want to create some **testContext**, call

```js
Object.defineProperty(**testContext**, "MyGlobalVar", {
        value: myGlobalVarValue,
        writable: false,
    });
```

and then run all `it()` in this context. Like use `runInContext()`

Problem: As far as I understand it, runInContext needs the code that will be executed in this testContext and I want to run it in a `beforeAll()` so I don't have the test code at this point.

How can I tell jest to run each test in the customized testContext that I have created?

I tried running

```js
beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(global, "MyGlobalVar", {
        value: MyGlobalVarValue,
        writable: true,
    });
});
```

this is worse but it does modify global space and I don't want that